# How to download a JSON Object array from URL, and Store for Android App?

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to integrate an API into an android application I am writing, but am having a nightmare trying to get the JSON array. The API has a URL that returns a an JSON array, but having never used JSON before I have no idea how this works, or how to do it.

I've looked and found tons, and tons of examples, but nothing to explain why/how it is done. Any help understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've ended up with, again with no understanding of JSON, it was a shot in the dark on my part (using examples/tutorials as a guide)...but it doesn't work :(

```
import org.json.*;          
//Connect to URL
        URL url = new URL("URL WOULD BE HERE");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();

//Get Data from URL Link
        int ok = connection.getResponseCode();
        if (ok == 200) {
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null)
          sb.append(line + '\n');
        //FROM HERE ON I'm Kinda Lost & Guessed
        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(sb.toString()); //ERROR HERE:complains it dosn't know what JSONValue is
        JSONArray array = (JSONArray)obj.get("response");
        for (int i=0; i < array.size(); i++) {
          JSONObject list = (JSONObject) ((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("list");
          System.out.println(list.get("name")); //Used to debug
        }
      }
```

***UPDATE/SOLUTION:***
So, it turns out that there was nothing wrong w/t the code. I was missusing what I thought it returns. I thought it was a JSONObject array. In actuality it was a JSONObjects wrapped in an array, wrapped in a JSONObject.

For those interested/ having similar issues, this is what I ended up with. I broke it into two methods. First connect/download, then:

```
private String[] buildArrayList(String Json, String Find) {
            String ret[] = null;
            try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(Json);
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("response");
            ret = new String[jArray.length()];

            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String var = json_data.getString(Find);
            ret[i] = var;
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ret;  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) use webservice to download your required Json string

2) convert it to your desired object using [Google Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list)

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
MyClass C1 = gson.fromJson(strJson, MyClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you used `JSONValue.parse()` that is invalid.

Insted of that Line write this code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(<String Value>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok my friend, i solved the same problem in my app with the next code:

1.- Class to handle the Http request:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static JSONObject jObj1 = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();            

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        //Log.e("JSONObject(JSONParser1):", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error json1" +
                "", "Error converting result json1:" + e.toString());
    }
    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        jObj1 = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser1:", "Error parsing data json1:" + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
}
```

Later, a class to handle the json info (Arrays, Objects, String, etc...)

```
public class ListViewer extends ListActivity{

TextView UserName1;
TextView LastName1;

 // url to make request
private static String url = "http://your.com/url";

// JSON Node names
public static final String TAG_COURSES = "Courses";    //JSONArray
//public static final String TAG_USER = "Users";    //JSONArray -unused here.

//Tags from JSon log.aspx All Data Courses.
public static final String TAG_COURSEID = "CourseId"; //Object from Courses
public static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";
public static final String TAG_INSTRUCTOR = "instructor";
public static final String TAG_LENGTH = "length";
public static final String TAG_RATING = "Rating";  //Object from Courses
public static final String TAG_SUBJECT = "subject";
public static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";


public static final String TAG_STATUS = "Status";  //Object from Courses    
public static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";  //Object from User
public static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "LastName";  //Object from User 

// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray Courses = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lay_main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> coursesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance (json2)
    JSONParser2 jParser2 = new JSONParser2();

    // getting JSON string from URL json2
    final JSONObject json2 = jParser2.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            try {

                // Getting Array of Contacts
                Courses = json2.getJSONArray(TAG_COURSES);
                // looping through All Courses      
                for(int i = 0; i < Courses.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject courses1 = Courses.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String courseID = courses1.getString(TAG_COURSEID);
                    //String status = courses1.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                    String Title = courses1.getString(TAG_TITLE);

                    String instructor = courses1.getString(TAG_INSTRUCTOR);
                    String length = courses1.getString(TAG_LENGTH);
                    String rating = courses1.getString(TAG_RATING);
                    String subject = courses1.getString(TAG_SUBJECT);
                    String description = courses1.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_COURSEID,courseID);
                    map.put(TAG_TITLE, Title);
                    map.put(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor);
                    map.put(TAG_LENGTH, length);
                    map.put(TAG_RATING, rating);
                    map.put(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                    //adding HashList to ArrayList
                    coursesList.add(map);
                }} //for Courses
                catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }

     //Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, coursesList,
            R.layout.list_courses,
            new String[] { TAG_COURSEID, TAG_TITLE, TAG_INSTRUCTOR, TAG_LENGTH, TAG_RATING, TAG_SUBJECT, TAG_DESCRIPTION }, new int[] {
                    R.id.txt_courseid, R.id.txt_title, R.id.txt_instructor, R.id.txt_length, R.id.txt_rating, R.id.txt_topic, R.id.txt_description });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        //@Override  --------check this override for onClick event---------
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String courseID = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_courseid)).getText().toString();
            String Title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title)).getText().toString();
            String instructor = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_instructor)).getText().toString();
            String length = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_length)).getText().toString();
            String rating = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_rating)).getText().toString();//Check place in layout
            String subject = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_topic)).getText().toString();// <- HERE
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_description)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);

            in.putExtra(TAG_COURSEID, courseID);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TITLE, Title);
            in.putExtra(TAG_INSTRUCTOR, instructor);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LENGTH, length);
            in.putExtra(TAG_RATING, rating);
            in.putExtra(TAG_SUBJECT, subject);
            in.putExtra(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });//lv.SetOnclickListener                      
}//onCreate
 }// Activity
```

in this case, i'll get the Arrays, objects... Hope this give you ideas...

Comment: In this case i store the info over a listview, if you want to store this in  SQLite, make your own DatabaseHelper class and call this methods (of the DatabseHelper.class) in your Main activity(or the activity where you want to save this info) to store the json objects.